# Cannot configure docker in intelliji

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have installed Docker on my Pop OS according to the official tutorial (I also created a docker user group and added myself to it). In IntelliJ Idea I am getting:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:/var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? No such file or directory`.

`systemctl status docker` shows that docker.service is active.

My permissions:

```
ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Feb 28 09:05 /var/run/docker.sock
```

[image]

Comment: can you paste the full commandline when intellij starts the configured profile?

Comment: @LeiYang I've added a screenshot from the Intellij

Comment: i mean when you run, check the output window, their should be a long command line to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue by re-installing Intellij. My version was from the pop-os application store and causes the problem, but the interesting fact - other things work as expected. So the version from the JetBrains toolbox did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to :

Add your `$user` to the `docker` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Log out, and then log back in.

[Docker configuration settings﻿:](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/docker-connection-settings.html#317f2f5)

> Unix socket: This is the recommended connection option for Linux.

> **note**

> If you get permission denied errors, add the current user to the docker group on the machine, log out, and then log back in. The docker group grants privileges equivalent to the root user. For details on how this impacts security in your system, see [Docker Daemon Attack Surface](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface).

Comment: thank you, but I mentioned in the post that I had already done that